# normrnd() and norm() operations without "for loop"

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization, normal-distribution, norm

I have been searching around to write the following code without the "for loop". I have looked into array operations such as `bsxfun()`,`arrayfun`, or other MATLAB built-in functions but could not really figure it out.

```
n = 10;
d= 2;

x = rand(n,d);
P_best = rand(n,d);
V_i = rand(n,d)
g = rand(1,d);
r_t = rand(n,1);


a1 = 0.91;
a2 = 0.21;
a3 = 0.51;
a4 = 0.58;

l = a1*a3/(n^a2*d^a4);

for i=1:n
    N_p(i,:) = 1.4962*r_t(i)*(normrnd(P_best(i,:),l*norm(x(i,:)-P_best(i,:),2))-x(i,:));
    N_g(i,:) = 1.4962*r_t(i)*(normrnd(g,l*norm(x(i,:)-g,2))-x(i,:));
end

V_o = 0.7298*V_i+N_p+N_g
```

Any solution would be much appreciated.
Also, my second questions is, will replacing the above loop reduce the run time especially for huge datasets? Are there any other tips that would reduce the run time? The reason I am asking such question is that I am working on big datasets and obviously reducing the run time of each step of my work will result in a considerable reduction in cost of the process.

Comment: Please explain the purpose of the code, ideally with an example including input and desired output

Comment: This is a sample of what I need in my main work. The random matrices that you see on top are just to prepare some sample data for my algorithm. The purpose of this code is to update the velocities of particles in Particle Swarm Optimization from `V_i` to `V_o`. What I am mainly looking for in my question is what to do instead of the "for loop".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Discussion and Code

You can remove that `loop` with a [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) based vectorized version -

```
N_g_sigma = l*sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus,x,g).^2,2));
N_g_normrnd = bsxfun(@plus,randn(size(N_g_sigma)).*N_g_sigma,g);
N_g = bsxfun(@times,N_g_normrnd - x,1.4962*r_t);

N_p_sigma = l*sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus,x,P_best).^2,2));
N_p_normrnd = bsxfun(@plus,randn(size(N_p_sigma)).*N_p_sigma,P_best);
N_p = bsxfun(@times,N_p_normrnd - x,1.4962*r_t);
```

It is based on a **hacked version of `normrnd.m`** as also exploited in another problem on `Stackoverflow` - [Improve speed of NORMRND for a family of distributions in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26674847/3293881) where it gave us huge speedup.

The thing to be noted that here is that `normrnd.m` uses random number generation given scalars `mu` and `sigma`, as shown in its syntax -

```
function r = normrnd(mu,sigma,varargin); 
%NORMRND Random arrays from the normal distribution...
```

With the proposed vectorized technique we are feeding an **array of `mu`'s and `sigma`'s rather than scalar values at each iteration** and thus bringing `vectorization` into effect.

---

### Quick runtime results

```
*****************  Datasize : n = 100000 , d = 10 *******************
-------------------------------------- With original loopy code
Elapsed time is 82.344671 seconds.
-------------------------------------- With Proposed vectorized code
Elapsed time is 0.033276 seconds.

*****************  Datasize : n = 10000 , d = 100 *******************
-------------------------------------- With original loopy code
Elapsed time is 7.776902 seconds.
-------------------------------------- With Proposed vectorized code
Elapsed time is 0.032324 seconds.
```

The huge speedups seen here are consistent with the speedups obtained with the [other `normrnd` related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26674847/3293881) that was vectorized as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It looks like what I am looking for. I will give it a try and post the outcome here.

Comment: @Omid Added some of my own runtime results!

Comment: I got very interesting results. I wish there was a way to attach images to this comment so, that way I could demonstrate my runtimes in form of a graph for different values of `n` and `d`. Anyways, the runtime did increase. The difference was even more significant when `n` was considerably large let's say above 500. The interesting part was that I did not see much of a difefernce runtime between `for` and `parfor`. I was expecting to see `parfor` performing better but saw opposite results. Any justfication for that? Or maybe I did not use `parfor` correctly.

Comment: @Omid Try some free image uploading site, like `http://postimage.org/` maybe and link it here? On the `parfor` thing, not an expert on that really, `bsxfun` does all the work for me anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry my bad, i have checked your question again and i cannot help with the part of removing for-loop. Just some recommendations on improving speed of your for loop:

```
% fastest way: Elapsed time is 0.000006 seconds.
tic
for i=n:1
  N_p(i,:) = 1.4962*r_t(i)*(normrnd(P_best(i,:),l*norm(x(i,:)-P_best(i,:),2))-x(i,:));
  N_g(i,:) = 1.4962*r_t(i)*(normrnd(g,l*norm(x(i,:)-g,2))-x(i,:));
end
toc

% slowest way: Elapsed time is 0.004444 seconds.
tic
for i=1:n
  N_p(i,:) = 1.4962*r_t(i)*(normrnd(P_best(i,:),l*norm(x(i,:)-P_best(i,:),2))-x(i,:));
  N_g(i,:) = 1.4962*r_t(i)*(normrnd(g,l*norm(x(i,:)-g,2))-x(i,:));
end
toc

% 2nd choice: Elapsed time is 0.000969 seconds.
tic
N_p2(n, 2) = nan;
N_g2(n, 2) = nan;
for i=1:n
  N_p2(i,:) = 1.4962*r_t(i)*(normrnd(P_best(i,:),l*norm(x(i,:)-P_best(i,:),2))-x(i,:));
  N_g2(i,:) = 1.4962*r_t(i)*(normrnd(g,l*norm(x(i,:)-g,2))-x(i,:));
end
toc
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a question, what will happen to those i's? Because there would be no loop anymore and I would imagine the variable "i" would not be defined.

Comment: Thanks for the comparison. It is veru helpful.