# matlab sum(X-Y) vs sum(X) - sum(Y)

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix

If we have two matrices `X` and `Y`, both two-dimensional, now mathematically we can say: `sum(X-Y)=sum(X)-sum(Y)`.

Which is more efficient in Matlab? Which is faster?

Comment: how about benchmarking using `tic` and `toc`?

Comment: @m.s. sum(X-Y) is a bit faster than sum(X)-sum(Y) , hmmmmm kind of answered my question , anyway why is that ?

Comment: how did you benchmark exactly? you should measure the execution times repeatedly in a loop (e.g. 1000) times and compare the results then.

Comment: `tic;sum(X-Y);toc;` executed this , sorry not very familiar with benchmarking

Comment: That is sort of expected as you are saving one function call with `sum(X-Y)`.

Comment: @Divakar hmmm good point, I just thought maybe matlab optimized the function sum, and doesn't it call some function when subtracting matrices ?

Comment: @niceman That `X-Y` certainly doesn't go through any function. As a sidenote really - Saving function calls with function-inling brings out noticeable speedups in MATLAB, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26674847/3293881) for one such example. Though function-inling isn't possible in your case.

Comment: @Divakar Not a function? try which -all minus

Comment: @siliconwafer It says: `... toolbox\matlab\ops\@double\minus)          % double method`. Don't think that's a function, or is it?

Comment: @Divakar That's a good question, actually. Internals are hidden... it's not an M-Function, not a MEX Function (that I can see), not P-Coded...

Comment: @Divakar It's a call to the `minus` method of the class `double` . That's a built-in, not implemented in MATLAB code, and it's a method rather than a pure function, but there's still a call involved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On my machine, `sum(x-y)` is slightly faster for small arrays, but `sum(x)-sum(y)` is quite a lot faster for larger arrays. To benchmark, I'm using MATLAB R2015a on a Windows 7 machine with 32GB memory.

```
n = ceil(logspace(0,4,25));

for i = 1:numel(n)
    x = rand(n(i));
    y = rand(n(i));
    t1(i) = timeit(@()sum(x-y));
    t2(i) = timeit(@()sum(x)-sum(y));
    clear x y
end

figure; hold on
plot(n, t1)
plot(n, t2)
legend({'sum(x-y)', 'sum(x)-sum(y)'})
xlabel('n'); ylabel('time')
set(gca, 'XScale', 'log', 'YScale', 'log')
```

[image]

Comment: ha ha ... by the time I finished redacting my post yours was already there ! Good job they show the same results (although your crossover seems to happen even earlier...)

Comment: Nice to see the plots!

Comment: So if both `sum` and `X-Y` are vectorized and they both do operations on all X and all Y, what is the reason for difference in time?

Comment: @Ben I don't know - it depends on exactly how `double.sum` and `double.minus` are implemented and vectorized, and on how the MATLAB JIT optimizes the two commands into operations (for all I know, it may optimize intelligently in a way that depends directly on the size of `x` and `y`, to take advantage of memory cache effects). And note that I only did benchmarking for an array of doubles - my answer may not hold true at all if `x` and `y` are other classes such as `uint8` or `logical`.

Answer (score 6):

You got me all curious and I decided to run some benchmark. By the time I was done it seems knedlsepp had it right as for larger matrices `sum(X-Y)` become quite slower.

The crossover seems to happen around `10^3` elements.

[image: img1]

```
%% // Benchmark code

nElem = (1:9).'*(10.^(1:6)) ; nElem = nElem(:) ;    %'//damn pretifier
nIter = numel(nElem) ;

res = zeros(nIter,2) ;
for ii=1:nIter
    X = rand(nElem(ii) ,1) ;
    Y = rand(nElem(ii) ,1) ;

    f1 = @() sum(X-Y) ;
    f2 = @() sum(X)-sum(Y) ;

    res(ii,1) = timeit( f1 ) ;
    res(ii,2) = timeit( f2 ) ;
    clear f1 f2 X Y
end

loglog(nElem,res,'DisplayName','nElem')
```

I ran that a few times and the results are quite consistent on my machine. I blew my memory trying to go above 10^7 elements. Feel free to extend the test but I don't think the relationship is going to change much.

---

Specs: Windows 8.1 Pro / Matlab R2013a on: [image: specs]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that both x and y have N x M = K elements, then
For sum(x)-sum(y) you have:

K memory access to read x, K memory access to read y, one memory access to write the result --> 2K + 1 memory access (Assuming that the intermediate sum inside the sum function will be held in a CPU register).

2K sum operations + 1 subtraction --> 2k + 1 CPU operations.

For sum(x - y):
Matlab will calculate x - y and store the output then calculate the sum, so we have K memory access to read x, K memory access to read y, K memory access to write the result of the subtraction, K memory access to read the subtraction result again for the sum function then 1 memory access to write the sum result --> 4K + 1 memory operations.

k subtractions + k summations  --> 2K operations.

As we can see sum(x - y) consumes many memory access, so in large number of elements it may consume higher time but I don't have an explanation why it's faster for small number of elements.

Comment: Good explanation for the – at first look – counterintuitive results of the other answers!

Comment: Can you estimate the average time for a memory access operation and a double precision plus/minus operation in CPU cycles or such, on some standard architecture like i7? I guess CPU cache size should have an effect?

Comment: Btw., while I respect your wish to write your name in your native script, it makes it hard to @mention you, at least for someone without extensive knowledge about Arabic.

Comment: @A. Donda you can estimate the memory access timing if you carefully studied the processor architecture and the memory specifications. For me, I don't have the needed experience with general purpose processors. I think also that the cache has a large effect.

Comment: @ A. Donda to mention me you can copy and paste my name. This will not require any Arabic knowledge.